# error with linq join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join

I have this linq query:

```
var segreterie = from s in db.USR_Utenti join h in db.USR_Accounts
                     on new {s.ID, settings.GruppoSegreteria} 
                     equals new {h.USR_UtentiReference,h.ID_Gruppo} select s;
```

that has this problem:

```
The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.
```

how can i do to solve it?

Answer (score 6):

The two types should be the same - which means they'll need the same property names as you're using anonymous types. Try this:

```
var segreterie = from s in db.USR_Utenti join h in db.USR_Accounts
                 on new {s.ID, Groups = settings.GruppoSegreteria} 
                 equals new {ID = h.USR_UtentiReference, Groups = h.ID_Gruppo}
                 select s;
```

That's assuming that `s.ID` and `h.USR_UtentiReference` have the same type, and `settings.GruppoSegreteria` and `h.ID_Gruppo` do likewise.

Answer (score 0):

On a similar note, if you are doing a join on a field which is nullable (for e.g., int and int?) you may have to do something like (where Field2 is int? in Table1 and int in Table2):

```
from l in Table1
join l2 in Table2
  on new { l.Field1, Field2 = (l.Field2.Value == null ? -1 : l.Field2.Value) } equals new { l2.Field1, Field2 = l2.Field2 }
```